# Passing the id in the controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with passing the id in the controller. I have a function of accepting and rejecting a request.

```
 @friend = Friend.find(params[:id])
 @friend.update(value_params)
```

When it updates it automatically updates the id of which user id created the value

I want to be able to the same but this time when it clicks accept or reject I want to get the id of the one who created the value and pass it as a parameter of `:for_id =>` inserting in the request and the updating the friend table

so the one who created the request will be the only one to see the request accepted or declined given his or her id

I tried using this but it wont insert into the database

```
@friend = Friend.find(params[:id])
@req = Request.new(:for_id => @friend)
```

No error it just doesn't include for_id in the insert clause or statement

Comment: is your insert causing an error? and if so what is the error?

Comment: no error it just doesnt include for_id in the insert clause or statement

Comment: Does your table `requests` have column `for_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it just doesnt include **for_id** in the insert clause or statement

please include this statement from your `server log`

also explain us what you are trying to accomplish, because you are not saving `@req` so I don't really see the reason why the server should do some `insert` statement.

If you want to have an insert statement

1. in case `friend has_many requests` then you should do:

   ```
   @friend.requests << @req 
   @friend.update(value_params)
   ```
2. else to save your `@req` in your db do:

   ```
   @req.save
   ```

This probably is wrong, but also a chance for you to explain us clearly what you are trying to accomplish